# Create a stack data structure

Tags: ruby, stack

I'm trying to create a Stack data structure in ruby filled with 3 trays. It's a LIFO data structure so the last item I add to the stack should be the first one to get out, but I'm having difficulty collecting the items in an array and feel like my syntax is wrong just to set this up in a basic fashion.

Code:

```
class Stack
attr_reader :item
@@contents = []
def initialize(item)
    @item = item
    @@contents << item 
end

def get_item
    @contents.pop
end


end

@a = Stack.new("tray1")
@b = Stack.new("tray2")
@c = Stack.new("tray3")
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood your question.  From your comment to Boris' answer it appears you just want to know how you could implement a stack, and that it is not a requirement that elements be added to the stack by creating instances of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait, you said LIFO? That's just `Array#push` and `#pop`:

```
class Stack < Array; end # Ruby Array is good enough stack. Just subclass without ado.

s = Stack.new [ "tray1", "tray2" ]
#=> ["tray1", "tray2"]

s.pop
#=> "tray2"

s
#=> ["tray1"]

s.push "tray3"
#=> ["tray1", "tray3"]

s.pop
#=> "tray3"  # last in first out

s.pop
#=> "tray1"  # stack is empty now
```

Comment: So if I was in a technical interview and was asked to create a stack this is all I would need to do? Is inheriting from the Array class perfectly fine?

Comment: All you would need to do is to say that in Ruby, `Array` has all the assets that make it a full-fledged stack, but if the matter is to demonstrate your programming prowess, you could easily create a `Stack` class without inheriting from `Array` (which would eg. wrap an array inside and delegate `#push` and `#pop` to it). You should end your expose in the interview by saying that the asker can move on to the next level of difficulty in the interview questions, that stacks and fizzbuzz are no problem for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would subclass `Array` rather than using it directly.

Comment: @TimMoore, I am not sure myself, probably because the asker in the sentence "I am trying to create a Stack data structure..." used the word "create" and capitalized "Stack".